# Highchart Renderer By min and max

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In Highcharts How to draw renderer Rectangle selection by using Min and Max values?

```
Chart.renderer.rect(x, y, width, height, 1);
```

At runtime only I can get min and max values and I dont know the width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getExtremes() function to return the data min for each axis.
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes%28%29

Search for 'translate' to see how to get the pixel values from that
highslide.com/forum/search.php?keywords=translate&fid[0]=9

You'll need to calculate the width and height based on the starting x and y values and the ending x and y values.